# Using animated.view with shared element in react-native

Tags: react-native

Today I noticed something very strange with react native `react-navigation-shared-element` and `reanimated 2.5.0` . So my problem is when i use animated view in shared element i got this error `Error: You attempted to set the key waitForRemoveSync with the value true on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.`  on Android, on IOS there is no problem . So my code so far

```
        <SharedElement id="image">
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              {
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                width: 64,
                height: 64,
                borderRadius: 64,
                backgroundColor: "yellow",
              },
              defaultSpringStyles,
            ]}
          >
            <AntDesign name={"edit"} size={22} color={"#fff"} />
          </Animated.View>
        </SharedElement>
```

[image]

So is there any way that i can use `animated.view` in `ShraedElement`

Comment: According to their documentation (https://github.com/IjzerenHein/react-native-shared-element#installation), I am not sure that you have to use an "Animated.View". Only a <View /> should works.

Comment: @lmasneri ye but on iphone it works but on android it doesn’t work. I want to find way how can i use animated  view in shared element?

Comment: I think you can't use Animated.View in SharedElements according to their documentation you might need to find a workaround.